# email sent from script with SMTP authentication using PEAR mail package still goes to Junk folder

Tags: php, email, pear, spam

I was having an issue with emails generated by a PHP script going to user's junk/spam email folders, and was led to believe that installing PEAR and the associated mail package and adding SMTP authentication would fix the issue.  So I do so using cPanel.  Unfortunately, after some testing, I find that emails are still going to my junk folder.  Below is the script in its current form.

I'm not sure what else to try to troubleshoot this. I contacted my provider and they just came back with some general info on spam/junk folders which wasn't very helpful!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Nick

```
<?php 
require_once "/home/..../php/Mail.php";

$from = ""; 
$to = ""; 
$subject = "Hi!"; 
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?"; 
$host = ""; 
$username = "";
$password = ""; 

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 
'To' => $to, 
'Subject' => $subject); 

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
array ('host' => $host, 
'auth' => true, 
'username' => $username, 
'password' => $password)); 

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) { 
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>"); 
} else { 
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all the things you can do to make your email more user friendly are exactly the same things as a spammer will do to disguise their spam. If a mail as basic as the one you're sending still ends in spam, there's not much you can do other than ask users to add your sending address to their whitelists.

Comment: Nothing will guarantee that the client wont mark email as spam.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I'm a little confused though.  On a previous site  I worked on I had basic PHP scripts sending emails, which didn't use PEAR and which didn't end up in people's spam folders.  The only thing that is different is I am using a different provider.  Would this make the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent and details example of both a form and the PEAR script - it might help you debug: https://solutions.hostmysite.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/8460/0/using-pear-mail-to-create-a-php-mail-form-that-uses-authenticationauthentication-is-required-by-hostmysite